# Symfony 2 Sitemap Google

Tags: performance, symfony, metadata, sitemap, apc

I have been developing a web page named: directorioelectronico.com and I have specially issues now, I will be very grateful that someone can be help me.

The web page has been submitted in Google.com and now all the links that are in the homepage are listed in search results BUT some links ej. google.com/maps are not list in the home page (because it appears only when you select your municipality). How can I tell to Google that it exists (maybe without a sitemap.xlm because my links have metadata that is very important that google knows?

In advance, Thank you very much for you help.

Comment: It seems you have two very different questions here. You should split your post into two.

Comment: you can provide metadata in a sitemap.xml

Comment: yes, but my issue is that when I have no setting cookies the home page redirect you to a page where you can select your municipality "/select-municipality" and when you select it now you can enter to the homepage "/" then Google and others searchers can not see the companies that are in a determinate municipality so how can I tell google that it exists?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was that I create a route /sitemap.xml and put it in robots.txt too I created an html page with all the sitemap with cities, companies and all imoportant links.